# Cannot run nuttcp inside Docker

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, patch

I am trying to run `nuttcp` inside a Docker container to measure it's UDP throughput. However, whenever I am starting the client instance, the server instance crashes with the following error message: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I found [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=745051) for Debian which says that `nuttcp` crashes because the file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_adv_win_scale` does not exist. I checked that file on another machine where `nettcp` is working and saw that the only content of that file was `1`. So I tried to add this file inside my Docker container like this:

```
root@7d4c0f0ffe4f:/proc/sys/net/ipv4$ echo 1 > tcp_adv_win_scale
bash: tcp_adv_win_scale: No such file or directory
```

So guess it is not possible to create this file manually. The bug report also includes a patch which can be applied to the source code (`nuttcp-6.1.2.c`) but since I installed `nuttcp` with `apt-get` I don't know how to apply that patch.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers run in their own [network namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html). Inside a namespace, you do not have access to all TCP system parameters; there's a [similar issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8674) in the Docker bugtracker, in which was stated that *"[t]hose aren't missing files in the container. That has to do with security and the kernel version."* So that's that, no way around this, unfortunately.

One solution that I could think of is to start the container within the host's network namespace, using the `--net=host` flag on startup. However, if your explicit goal is to measure the network throughput of Docker's network stack, that's probably not an option for you.

Alternatively, you can patch nuttcp yourself by following [this tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial) on how to apply custom patches to Debian packages. This basically boils down to the following:

1. installing the source package with `apt-get source <package>`
2. installing build dependencies with `apt-get build-dep <package>`
3. applying the patch to the source code using `dpatch`
4. building the modified package with `debuild -b -uc -us`
5. and installing the modified package with `dpkg -i <package>.deb`

Comment: I just found the binary of a more recent version (7.3.3) [here](http://nuttcp.net/nuttcp/nuttcp-7.3.3/nuttcp-7.3.3.x86_64) from the developers website. This one runs without problems. But thank you for explaining how to apply the patch.